# Django Template Tag `url` not working as expected

Tags: django, django-templates

So currently, I have the following code:

```
patterns.append(url(r'^sales/crudeoilsale/$', LVCla.as_view(), name='crudeoilsale-list'))
```

With a link that references it as:

```
<a class="nav-model-container" href="{% url 'crudeoilsale-list' %}"></a>
```

Running this code however gives me the error

```
NoReverseMatch at /office/
Reverse for 'crudeoilsale-list' not found. 'crudeoilsale-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Checking my url list though, it returns this:

```
^admin/
office/ ^$ [name='office-index']
office/ ^sales/crudeoilsale/$ [name='crudeoilsale-list']
office/ ^sales/tubosale/$ [name='tubosale-list']
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you missing a namespace, e.g. `{% url 'office:crudeoilsale-list' %}`? Doing `patterns.append()` is a bit unusual - how does the rest of the urls.py look?

Comment: Hey it worked! Thanks Alasdair.

You're right, I did have it registered like django registers `admin` - `url(r'office/', sites.office.urls)` I didn't realize I needed the `office:` to connect everything. Thanks again!